# Для чего нужны template template parameters?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Для чего нужны `template template parameters` в шаблонных классах и функциях, ведь можно передавать им аргументы, которые являются шаблонами, с помощью обычных `type parameters`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это смотря что вы имеете в виду под "передавать им аргументы, которые являются шаблонами, с помощью обычных type parameters".

- Шаблон является шаблоном только пока у него остались незафиксированные параметры. Когда для всех параметров шаблона указаны конкретные аргументы это уже никакой не шаблон. Шаблон функции превращается в обычную функцию, а шаблон типа - в обычный тип. Поэтому, с одной стороны, когда вы передаете через type parameters *уже специализированный* шаблон, то такой шаблон уже **не является** *шаблоном*. Это уже просто *тип*, готовый "замороженный" конкретный тип, в котором не осталось ничего шаблонного. Его в общем случае уже нельзя "переспециализовать" в другой тип.

  А template template parameters - это не окончательно отлитые в граните типы, это еще живые подвижные *шаблоны*. Их можно свободно специализировать налево и направо с разными аргументами. Например

  ```
  template <template <typename T, typename = std::allocator<T>> class Container> struct S
  {
    Container<int> ints;
    Container<double> doubles;
  };

  ...
  S<std::vector> sv;
  S<std::list> sl;
  ```

  Каким образом вы собираетесь это делать через "обычный type parameter"?
- С другой стороны, шаблоны действительно можно передавать через "обычные type parameters". Шаблон можно объявить членом обычного класса, а затем передавать этот обычный класс через "обычный type parameter", тем самым вместе с ним передавая и "завернутый" в него шаблон. То есть с этой точки зрения template template parameters являются избыточными (как, впрочем, и template non-type parameters) - всех их можно симулировать через обычные type parameters.

  Отвечая на свой же вопрос, заданный выше

  ```
  struct TraitsV
  {
    template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>> 
    using Container = std::vector<T, A>;
  };

  struct TraitsL
  {
    template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T>> 
    using Container = std::list<T, A>;
  };

  template <typename Traits> struct S
  {
    typename Traits::template Container<int> ints;
    typename Traits::template Container<double> doubles;
  };

  ...
  S<TraitsV> sv;
  S<TraitsL> sl;
  ```

Из вашего вопроса не ясно, о каком именно из этих двух пунктов вы ведете речь.

Comment: Есть случаи, когда невозможно передать аргумент вторым способом, но можно с помощью `template template`?

Comment: @nikita: Вряд ли. Второй способ скорее более гибок, хоть и более громоздок.

Answer (score 0):

Например чтобы делегировать инстанцирование этого шаблона целевому шаблону. Т.е. предоставить ему возможность самостоятельно выбирать параметры для передаваемого шаблона. Например:

```
template
<
    typename x_Value
,   template
    <
         typename xx_Value
    ,    typename xx_Allocator
    > class x_Container
> class t_Fancy
{
    private: class
    t_CustomAllocator{...};

    private: using
    t_Container = x_Container<x_Value, t_CustomAllocator>;

};
```